# scrollable div with border HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

How can i code a scrollable div ? perfectly with a blue border.

Is there a way to code this?

Like a window in a window -> two scrollbars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the id of your div but mine is `box`.

Add this to your code:

```
#box {
    width: 1620px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: #254C58 1px 0px;
    border: #3C7D91 5px double; 
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 433px;
}
```

Comment: he asked for two scrollbar so just give overflow:scroll

Comment: @oz2311 Thats perfect thank you!!

Comment: no problem @JSProgrammer11

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scroll **horizontally**, add `overflow-x:scroll` to your CSS and when your div expands past its defined width it will become scrollable.

Inversely, `overflow-y:scroll` should be added to allow **vertical** scrolling as well under the same circumstances.